# Incorrect usage of unless

Tags: unless, conditionals

Why can't the conditional

> I would go to bed if I wasn't waiting for a phone call

be transformed thus

> I would go to bed unless I was/wasn't waiting for a phone call

A student asked me why this second version is wrong and I was stumped and unable to give a reasonable answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Very interesting question, and I hadn't noticed the problem before.

[English Grammar Today](http://dictionary.cambridge.org/grammar/british-grammar/unless) says:

"We don’t use **unless** for things that we know to be true:

> *You won’t be able to get a ticket for the match unless you’re prepared to pay a lot of money for it.* (The speaker doesn’t know if you’re prepared to pay a lot of money for a ticket.)
>
> *I don’t know what we would have done if we hadn’t seen you.* (We did see you.)
>
> Not: *I don’t know what we would have done unless we’d seen you.* "

I think this is the point that excludes your sentence: I know whether or not I am waiting for a call at the moment, so I cannot use *unless*. If I were talking generally, or about a time in the future (when I would not know), then I could use it:

> *In those days, I would go to bed unless I was waiting for a phone call.* (non-specific occasion in the past)
>
> *On work days, after 11 I would go to bed unless I was waiting for a phone call.* (non-specific occasion, past present or future)
>
> *I'll go to bed unless I'm waiting for a phone call.* (occasion in the future)

Comment: Shouldn't it be "I would go to bed if I **weren't** waiting for a phone call." and "I would go to bed unless I **were** waiting for a phone call."?

Answer (score 1):

These two:*

> I would go to bed **if I wasn't** waiting for a phone call.
>   I would go to bed **unless I was** waiting for a phone call.

Describe the same situation:

- Waiting for phone call → stay up
- Not waiting for phone call → go to bed

The difference is that *if I wasn't* implies that the speaker is currently waiting for a call, and therefore that they're describing the present situation.
I would use *unless I was* in a more hypothetical context, like “At 11 pm on a school night, I would go to bed, unless I was waiting for a phone call.”

* *Unless I wasn't* just reverses the logic: only go to bed if waiting for a call.